# Android Alarms: setRepeating vs set & reschedule

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm in the process of creating an app that will remind the user of something X times per day, every day. I'm wondering if it's better to create:

- Multiple `setRepeating` alarms with a 24-hour interval
- One `setRepeating` alarm with a 1-hour interval [or half-hour] and decides whether to remind or just return
- One `set` alarm that sets the "next" alarm when run
- OR something else I haven't though of...

More specifically, what do I gain by using one method over the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your primary goal should be to invoke as few alarms as possible, particularly with `_WAKEUP` alarms, to save battery life. Hence, your second bullet is not the best solution.

Your secondary goal should be to minimize the amount of code you need to maintain these alarms, just to simplify your life.

Usually, I think of "X times per day, every day" as being "every N hours" or something. In that case, a single `setRepeating()` call would suffice.

If the "X times per day, every day" isn't quite that regular (e.g., alarms at 8am, noon, and 4pm, but not 8pm, midnight, or 4am), then your first bullet is probably the simplest.

If the "X times per day, every day" isn't even that regular, then I'd go with your third bullet.

Comment: Well it will probably be something like s-th at a set time and then Friday/Saturday with a different time